# Is there a server API for the Messaging for Web product?

Tags: rest-api, messaging-for-web

I have a custom chat client that is using the [Chat REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_API_requests.htm). Given the product is in maintenance mode I'm looking at what will be needed to support Messaging for Web.

However, all I found was [a JS API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-web/references/m4w-reference/overview.html). Is there a server API I'm just not finding? Or should the same REST API as chat be used?